# Table update Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, database, visual-studio, azure, sql-server-2017

Visual Studio 2017 crashes and restarts when I create a new table in my database and click "Update"

I have created a database for my application and I am trying to create a new table in the database. After I create the table, I try to click on "Update" so the table can be saved, but the moment that I click "Update" the application stops and pop up comes up that says "VS 2017 has stopped... trying to diagnose" and then after a few seconds another pop up says "Restarting VS2017" and it restarts visual studio without saving the table that I was trying to create

I tried to repair it but it does't work

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there is not enough information presented to debug the crash.

Comment: How did you create the database? And how are you trying to add a table to it from Visual Studio? Where are you hosting the database?
"I tried to repair it but it doesn't work" How did you try to repair it? And why didn't it work? Did you get any error messages, or is the behavior still the same?
As you can see there are a lot of questions we need some answers to before we can actually start to help you. Please refer to [mcve]

Comment: I just do:
Add New item ==> Service-based Database
Table s==> Add new table
I added the table's information and when i click "update" the VS restarts
There isn't any error message

"I tried to repair it but it doesn't work" i mean:
VS installer ==> repair

Answer (score 0):

Judging on your post and the comment you added, you've used the **Service-based database** which is available when having the **Data storage and processing workload** installed. The menu-item you're specifying seems to be used to add a new `.mdf` file, which is a database, not a table.

To add a Table, use the Table Designer like specified in [Create tables and keys by using Table Designer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/data-tools/create-a-sql-database-by-using-a-designer?view=vs-2017#create-tables-and-keys-by-using-table-designer).

> In Server Explorer or SQL Server Object Explorer, expand the Data Connections node, and then expand the .mdf node.
>
> Open the shortcut menu for Tables, and then select Add New Table.
>
> The Table Designer opens and shows a grid with one default row, which represents a single column in the table that you're creating. By adding rows to the grid, you'll add columns in the table.

More info: [Create a database and add tables in Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/data-tools/create-a-sql-database-by-using-a-designer?view=vs-2017)